# open stream pdf in IE using angular

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, blob

I would open a pdf file in the navigator

Actually Chrome is working . when click on file pdf is getting open in new window

```
public openFile(path) {
  let url='/download/';
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  let pathFile= new HttpParams().set('pathFile', path);
  return this.httpClient.get(url,{params:pathFile, responseType: 'blob'})
}
```

then in my component

```
openFile(path){
  this.creditPoliciesService.openFile(path).toPromise().then (data => {
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'}); 
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
    window.open(fileURL);
});
```

In Internet Expolorer and Firefox when I click on the link a new tab get opened then in the url bar I get this adress `blob:http://......code....`

How can I read blob in IE ?